# Create a node.js native extension on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, native, add-on

I'm trying to access a particular native Windows API call from within a node.js application. I believe that the best way to do this is to create a native extension / addon to node that I can require in my node.js application and call from the JavaScript.

Where can I find resources on how to actually compile this sort of executable? I can find instructions on how to write it, but all the build instructions seem to be for Linux. I'm fine with compiling through g++ on mingw, I don't need to use Visual Studio. Also, where do I find the header files that I need in order to compile the extension?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi/) will help you. It's simple and it's works.

```
npm install ffi
```

```js
var FFI = require('ffi');

function TEXT(text){
   return new Buffer(text, 'ucs2').toString('binary');
}

var user32 = new FFI.Library('user32', {
   'MessageBoxW': [
      'int32', [ 'int32', 'string', 'string', 'int32' ]
   ]
});

var OK_or_Cancel = user32.MessageBoxW(
   0, TEXT('I am Node.JS!'), TEXT('Hello, World!'), 1
);
```

Comment: Cool, I've never seen this project before.

Comment: Important to note: *There is non-trivial overhead associated with FFI calls. Comparing a hard-coded binding version of `strtoul()` to an FFI version of `strtoul()` shows that the native hard-coded binding is **5x** faster. So don't just use the C version of a function just because it's faster. There's a significant cost in FFI calls, so make them worth it.*  In other words, this is fine for occasional calls to a native API, but if you're going to be making a lot of native calls, you're going to have to write your own addon to avoid the significant overhead of node-ffi.

Comment: Why do i see Chinese characters as output?

Answer (score 14):

This is now out of date.  Today, use [nan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nan) and [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) to write and build native modules that work across platforms.

---

I've gone through this pain myself.  [Here's a guide that helped me get it working. (PDF)](http://coderesearchlabs.com/articles/BNWCA.pdf)  Remember that since Node is now officially supported on Windows, Visual Studio is the recommended build tool for Node on Windows.

Basically:

- [Download](http://nodejs.org/#download) and build the Node source code.  (See PDF)
- Create a new VC++ Win32 solution in VS, selecting DLL as the application type in the wizard that follows.  Make sure ATL/MFC is unchecked.
- Write your addon.  As an example, [here's one I wrote that gets Windows' current DNS settings](https://github.com/daguej/node-winnetinfo).  Specifically, the [project's settings file (vcxproj)](https://github.com/daguej/node-winnetinfo/blob/master/NodeWinNetInfo/NodeWinNetInfo.vcxproj#L42) will be of interest since one of the toughest parts is getting all the library references/include paths set up.  You might want to borrow my config and replace `D:\node\` with the location of your Node repo.