# Accessing USB devices from node-webkit?

Tags: html, node.js, webkit, v8, node-webkit

I'm building a node-webkit app that needs to run on all 3 main desktop environments (windows, mac and linux) I need my app to connect to a plugged in USB device and I'm having a bit of trouble working out exactly how to go about this.

Is there an npm that would work across all OS's? Could I get one built in C++ that would work? Is there anything built in to node-webkit for interacting with devices (Devices API?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More information is needed to answer this.  What kind of USB device?  Does it have drivers?  Why don't any of the [modules listed on npm](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=usb) work?

Comment: The device is a GPS unit. The stuff on NPM require complex build processes and only unix based platforms. We wont control the end user environment (in which this will run) so a complex multi file specific build is no good for us. We have a drivers for the device.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost certain to need a C/C++ module to make this happen, which means a build process is required.  The good news is that you can just do the build on your machine and distribute the resulting binaries (x86 and x64) for Windows and OS X.  Linux might be a little trickier, but on the other hand it's more likely to have a working build environment.

There are a few approaches, in order of ease:

- If your GPS device can present itself as a simple serial device (a COM port on Windows, or `/dev/tty-usbserial` on *nix), then you can just use [serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) to connect to the device and receive raw data.  There's a [nmea](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nmea) module that can handle parsing the data.  serialport works out of the box on all 3 platforms.

  If the drivers don't have an official option to present the device as a serial device, you may be able to find an unsupported way to make it happen with some searching.
- If the GPS device's drivers don't expose the device as a serial device, you'll need to write a [C++ module](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) that interfaces with the driver.  You'll need to write code for all three platforms; the device manufacturer should provide documentation/an SDK.  ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625030/201952) for advice about getting started with native modules on Windows.)
- Last resort: you may be able to use the [usb](https://www.npmjs.org/package/usb) module to communicate directly with the device.  This will probably involve reverse engineering the protocol that the device uses to communicate with the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to execute a `command line` script for that. Caution, it is platform-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need any module you can use chrome usb api its already available for node webkit and electron applications https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb

Comment: Future visitors don't care when an answer was posted, just that it is there when they visit. There is never a need to mention how 'late' you posted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes you are right i have edited my answer

Comment: FYI - there is a note on the Chrome.usb API that suggests certain USB devices may not show up.  In my experience, I've had differences using the chrome.usb API on Mac vs PC, and with certain Flash Sticks, they don't show up at all.