# Node webkit application with USB module failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, node-webkit

I am writing an desktop application using node-webkit. I have written script using Node USB module which is working fine if i run that script using node. It lists all usb devices , connects,reads,writes. Now I want to achieve same using node-webkit application where HTML has a button on which we have to do these things. Now for this we require to configure node modules. I have added that module to my project and then did process as mentioned

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "node-webkit-angular-bootstrap-starter",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Starter destkop app using node-webkit, html5, angular, and bootstrap",
  "main": "app/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "window": {
    "title": "node-webkit-angular-bootstrap-starter",    
    "toolbar": true,
    "frame": true,
    "width": 1024,
    "height": 768,
    "position": "center"
  },
  "dependencies"  : {
    "node-pre-gyp": "0.6.9"
  },
  "bundledDependencies":["node-pre-gyp"],
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "~2.0.0-rc.15"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build"
  },
  "binary": {
    "module_name": "usb",
    "module_path": "./app/lib/binding/",
    "host": "https://github.com/camsoupa/node-usb"
  }
}
```

`Home.js`:

```
(function () {    'use strict';  app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {alert("Heelooooo");


var gui = require('nw.gui');
var os = require('os'); 

$scope.settings = [];
$scope.usb = require('usb');   });})();
```

I am getting following error for running the application using nw

```
"%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
↵D:\Projects\…er\node_modules\usb\src\binding\usb_bindings.node"}
```

Can some one please help me?

Comment: I have same issue. The usb module refuses to work, even after compiling with nw-gyp and the proper incantations for the correct nwjs version.

Comment: please check my answer to this question it could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39405308/427622

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in my case by compiling for the correct architecture. In my environment, node is 32-bit while nw is 64-bit. Changing directories to the usb module, the following two commands resolved the issue by creating a 64-bit version of the native bindings:

```
nw-gyp configure --target=0.12.3 --module_name=usb_bindings --module_path=..\src\binding\ --target_arch=x64

nw-gyp build --target=0.12.3 --module_name=usb_bindings --module_path=..\src\binding\ --target_arch=x64
```

The `module_name` and `module_path` variables are necessary because for whatever reason, `nw-gyp` isn't getting their values from the `binding.gyp` file.

One more thing that can cause the error you described is renaming `nw.exe` to something else. As long as it is named `nw.exe`, the symbols will bind correctly.